# Testing Winter '15 - New Clause USING SCOPE values

Tags: soql, list-view, territory-management, territory

I am trying to test "Using Scope" on a custom object, **orders** which has a MD relation to **Account**.
I'm trying to filter a list view of Orders to show only by User's territory, like we have in **Account** list view option. I tried the following...

> SELECT id, name FROM orders__c USING SCOPE MyTerritory

But it seems it's not the right way. Please guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: do u get any error when you run this soql ?

Comment: I ran on workbench soql. It didn't recognize after "SELECT id, name FROM orders__c"

Comment: did you select version 32 in workbench ?

Comment: nope. let me check

Comment: I chechked and found v32.0 is not supported. v31.0 is working though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as you mentioned **USING SCOPE** is new with Winter 15 .. and you can use it with API version 32..

If you are using Workbench, select api version 32 when you login or change your api version to 32 in your session settings after you logged in to workbench and give it a try.. it should work..

when i run the below  query in Developer Console in my sandbox which is Winter 15 I get the results fine..

```
Select Id from Account USING SCOPE Mine
```

but when i run the same query in Developer Console in production which is still Summer 14, i get an error saying unrecognised query ..

> Note : I tried the same query with custom objects as well and it works
>   fine in Winter 15 sandbox

Comment: So you mean, if I use v32, I will be able to do SOQL query filtering on custom objects according to my Territory? No need to query accountshare,group and territory?